# URL Rewrite Issues

Tags: angularjs, iis, web-config

This question has been asked but when I try it I can't seem to get it to work, here is my issue, I have to redirect all requests to index.html except for one folder , we have an api folder called "Mercury" that already has a rewrite rule for stripping out an index file in a folder , 
it looks like this

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Strip out index.cfm">
        <match url="(*)Mercury/(*)"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}Mercury/index.cfm/{R:2}"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I want to set a second rule that basically takes all requests and points them to index.html so /products would not point to a folder but to index.html, so standard spa setup , but I want to ensure it doesn't effect the current rule. This is the issue I am having, any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for html5 enabled angular routes, you can alter the folder and filenames in the match tag to exclude the folders you desire.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS">
            <match url="(API/*|cordova.js|scripts/*|views/.*|templates/.*|assets/.*|lib/.*|bower_components/.*|test/.*)" negate="true" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: do I use both or just replace the original with the new one ?

Comment: Replace with new one